Create FIR bandpass filter from lowpass and highpass filters
I am trying to implement in Python a bandpass FIR filter based on a lowpass and a highpass filter with different number of taps. For what I have found in online resources I could do one of these:

Estimate lowpass and highpass filters and then convolve them into the bandpass filter

\\ lowpass
a = 1
b = firwin(257, lowF, pass_zero=False, fs=sampling_rate)
lowpassed_trace = filtfilt(b, a, data)
\\ highpass
b = firwin(129, highF, pass_zero=False, fs=sampling_rate)
highpass_trace = filtfilt(b, a, data)
\\ convolution
bandpass_trace = convolve(lowpassed_trace, highpassed_trace, mode="same")


Compute one filter and then apply the other filter on it

\\ lowpass
a = 1
b = firwin(257, lowF, pass_zero=False, fs=sampling_rate)
lowpassed_trace = filtfilt(b, a, data)
\\ bandpass by applying highpass filter on lowpass trace
b = firwin(129, highF, pass_zero=False, fs=sampling_rate)
bandpass_trace = filtfilt(b, a, lowpassed_trace)


Same as above but the cutoff frequencies for lowpass and highpass are reversed.

Are any of these correct or am I way off? As you can tell I am not specialist on DSP. Any hints will be greatly appreciated!

If the data is not a Dirac delta, the outputs in 1. and 2. are completely different. In 1. you are convolving two signals which are obtained at the output of the lowpass and highpass (note that when using filtfilt the effective frequency response of the filter is $|H(f)|^{2}$). In 2. you can achieve bandpass filtering if highF < lowF. I'm wondering why you don't design a bandpass FIR filter from the get-go?

Because we would like to use different number of taps on the lowpass and highpass filters. I don't understand quite well why we want to do this, but we would like to replicate what we observe on a filter implemented on a FPGA where the specs from the vendor claim to use 2 different number of taps.

Let's call the the high pass $h[n] \leftrightarrow H[k]$, the lowpass $l[n] \leftrightarrow L[k]$ the input $x[n]$ and the output $y[n]$. What we want is simply
$$y[n] = x[n]*l[n]*h[n] \leftrightarrow Y[k] = X[k]\cdot L[k]\cdot H[k]$$
where $*$ is the convolution operator. Both convolution and multiplication are commutative so it doesn't matter in which order we apply the filters.

Estimate lowpass and highpass filters and then convolve them into the bandpass filter

That's wrong. This implements
$$y_1[n] = (l[n]*x[n])*(h[n]*x[n]) \leftrightarrow Y_1[k] = X[k] \cdot X[k] \cdot L[k]\cdot H[k]$$
So you end up convolving the signal with itself which is really not what you want.

Compute one filter and then apply the other filter on it

That's fine

Same as above but the cutoff frequencies for lowpass and highpass are reversed.

Sorry, but that's nonsense. You can certainly reverse the order of the the filter but NOT the crossover frequencies. If the crossover frequency of the highpass is higher than that of the lowpass you end up essentially with a "no-pass".

lowpassed_trace = filtfilt(b, a, data)

This makes no sense to me. Why would you use filtfilt() with an FIR filter that's already linear phase?
In general the best method would be to design the specific bandpass you want in the first place and apply that as a single filter. This gives you the most control and the best efficiency.

thanks for your reply! So, if I understood you well, you would advice me to do number 2 in my list, except for the use of filtfilt. What would you recommend instead?

No. I would recommend to design a bandpass filter per your requirements and than apply using functions like filter(), fftifilt(), convolve() (in Matlab, Python would be different). If you don't know what the differences between those are, I would recommend taking a few classes first. It's hard to do DSP without understanding the underlying fundamentals and the math behind it.
